# Although everything is fine, React Router does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to link pages using React Reuters but As far as I know everything is fine but none of the components are working properly

**َApp.js**

```
import React from "react";
import MatherComponent from "./components/MatherComponent";
import AboutMe from "./components/AboutMe";
import NoPage from "./components/NoPage";
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import { BrowserRouter, Route , Routes } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                        <Route index element={<MatherComponent />} />
                        <Route path="about" element={<AboutMe />} />
                        <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Layout**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout() {
    return (
        <>
            <header className="row" style={{ padding: "10px", backgroundColor: '#ffc107', display: 'flex', marginLeft: "0px", marginRight: "0px" }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }} className="col col-4">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/48/000000/apple-weather.png" alt="" />
                    <div style={{ marginRight: "10px", paddingTop: "10px" }}>آب و هوای امروز</div>
                </div>
                <div className="col col-4">
                    <button style={{ float: "left" }} className="btn">
                        <img alt="" src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/48/000000/external-thermometer-weather-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons.png" />
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="col col-4">
                    <Link to="/about">About Me</Link>
                </div>
            </header>
        </>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

That is, it only shows the layout and does not show the other components

Answer (score 0):

The `Layout` component is missing an `Outlet` for the nested `Route` components to be rendered in.

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

```
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout() {
  return (
    <>
      <header className="row" style={{ padding: "10px", backgroundColor: '#ffc107', display: 'flex', marginLeft: "0px", marginRight: "0px" }}>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }} className="col col-4">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/48/000000/apple-weather.png" alt="" />
          <div style={{ marginRight: "10px", paddingTop: "10px" }}>آب و هوای امروز</div>
        </div>
        <div className="col col-4">
          <button style={{ float: "left" }} className="btn">
            <img alt="" src="https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/48/000000/external-thermometer-weather-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons.png" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="col col-4">
          <Link to="/about">About Me</Link>
        </div>
      </header>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit although-everything-is-fine-react-router-does-not-work]

[Forked codesandbox from your project repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/although-everything-is-fine-react-router-does-not-work-367d72).

Comment: But sir, I will make the change after this, it is the same as before

Comment: @Mahiatavakkoli From what I can tell it's working as I'd expect it to. I updated my answer to include a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/although-everything-is-fine-react-router-does-not-work-815fr) demo, please check it out.

Comment: @Mahia Were you able to resolve your question/issue with my answer? Is there anything still to address?

Comment: Yes, thank you, you can see the complete code from GateHub https://github.com/mahia1386/Weather

Comment: @Mahia The code in your repo had an error with importing a font file into CSS in `src/Font/style.css`. I've fixed that issue, and then fixed your `App` component so it now renders `Layout` on a layout route, wrapping the nested routes. https://codesandbox.io/s/although-everything-is-fine-react-router-does-not-work-367d72